# perl ssh to remote server, start service and capture pid

Tags: perl, ssh

title: perl ssh to remote server, start service and capture pid

1-please tell me if i am not clear, or i if am otherwise frustrating as i ask questions - i do not want to bite the hand that feeds me!

2-original file is 180 lines long, but here is the gist:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SSH::Expect;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep nanosleep);
Time::HiRes::sleep(5); #5 seconds #a look at "top" verifies this running .pl file pid.

my $remoteCmd = `ssh $remote_host -l $userID -i /home/$userID/.ssh/authorized_keys /sbin/service  /etc/init.d/c3-mi-nodeserver start`;
my $servicePID = $$; #this should be pid for .pl file running.
print "servicePID: " . $servicePID . "\n"; #prints the pid of the running .pl file.
```

of course, you'll see variables that i populate to make it work.
one idea i have is: if i start a service, it will be the pid # of the currently running .pl file + 1; *but*, the new service started is on a remote server, so how can i capture it from the remote server and return it back to the local .pl file?

ideas?

Comment: You can't guarantee that a started pid will be pid+1 - that's a very dangerous sort of race condition.

Comment: Also, why using backticks when you use already ssh modules ?

Comment: perhaps no super good reason; but i had not gotten the ssh to work another way than in the back ticks. currently, aborting the ssh from server to server, and going to run the utility only on the local server. security reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that ssh command there's no way to capture the PID of the process you just started on a remote host.

You would need to use *another* ssh to find the process id. But really - what are you trying to accomplish by doing so? Can you not use `service status` and `service stop` to manipulate it?

If you really need a pid - `service status` might do it - or running a ps command.

Comment: Hi, Sobrique - the idea is, once i start a service then check it by using the pid # generated when i started it. i'm afraid a service status may give me a pid of a child process or just not the exact service i just started. if we're in a tough spot here, i'll pursue something like: "if (RESULT_OF_STATUS =~ /is running/ ){", etc. i'll check back, but will begin to pursue regex of a service status command. i'll also contemplate another ssh which could get $$ [pid#] of the current .pl file + 1, which should give the pid of the process it just started[eg, its newly started service]. many thanks!!

Comment: The whole point of the `service` mechanism is that it lets you test things without having to bodge your own. However I will re-iterate.  `$$ + 1` is NOT guaranteed to be your new process ID - it may be generally, but it will break horribly at some point.

Comment: yah, pid +1 by nature sounds weak at best. have had challenges with this ssh to remote servers getting process name and pid, plus checking status of a server, or doing kill -0, or starting/stopping services. putting code now on individual servers local to the services we're monitoring. thx!!